# React w/ Redux/React-Redux and Redux-Persist only persisting first change to local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm having a few issues with persisting `Redux` in React using `React-Redux` and `Redux-Persist`.

**Reducer Example:**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "SET_FOO":
        return action.payload
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

**Action Example:**

```
const setFooAction = (payload) => {
    return {
      type: "SET_FOO",
      payload
    }
  }
  export default setFooAction;
```

**Index.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import fooReducer from "redux/reducers/setFooReducer";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foo: fooReducer 
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

let state = {
  foo: {}
}

let store = createStore(
    persistedReducer, 
    state, 
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
let persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Usage in component:**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import setFoo from "redux/actions/setFooAction";

class Main extends Component {        
    //... More Code
    componentDidMount() {
        let foo = this.getFoo() //Gets foo, doesn't really exist but just for context
        this.props.setFoo(foo); //Works fine, all gets set, data is persisted
    }    
    addNewFoo = () => {    
        //Called after functions runs somewhere    
        let newFoo = this.getNewFoo() //Gets newFoo, doesn't really exist but just for context
        foo.push(newFoo)
        this.props.setFoo(foo); //Sets Redux store, on refresh, doesn't persist    
    }
    //...More Code    
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  ...state,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   setFoo: (payload) => dispatch(setFoo(payload)) 
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

**Initially**, everything works fine:

- The app loads
- Initial state is set across the app
- This updates the Redux storage
- `PERSIST` fires, and it's stored in local storage.
- On refresh, everything persists as expected from the first load of data.
- The first update of each of the various objects in the Redux store.

**However...**

If I decide to add anything new into my objects and set/update them into the Redux store...

... on refresh, only what was originally persisted is still present during `REHYDRATE` (if I am understanding the Redux events right).

Now I believe this is something to do with my objects immutability and Redux not picking up changes because of that, but I have attempted to alter my reducers without any luck:

**Reducer Attempt:**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => Object.assign(state, {
   foo: action.payload !== "SET_FOO" ? state.foo : action.payload
});
```

I tried the above (and also a combintation of this and my original which just broke things). This sort of worked, but was setting my state as follows:

```
state {
    foo: {
        foo: {
           //Foo data
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it's just assigning to `foo` again because of the addition `foo:` in the reducer...

...however, I am unsure how to correct this without potentially doing something wrong in `Redux`!

So, my caution has prevailed and I thought best to ask if anyone has any suggestions or threads that I can pull at!

Thanks for any help in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems good at first glance.

Your `Object.assign` in the reducer may be what is causing the nested `foo` objects, because of one on Redux principles that is immutability so you should always return a new state, instead, you're mutating directly the `state`.

You can add one first parameter more, to create a new object that will have the state properties with the new foo one:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => Object.assign({}, state, {
   foo: action.payload !== "SET_FOO" ? state.foo : action.payload
});
```

A better approach and that you will see often will be:

```
export default (state = {}, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'SET_FOO': {
      return { ...state, payload }
    }

    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

In this last example, you can clearly visualize that I'm returning a new object with all the properties that the state has, plus the new payload.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right path, I had to spread `...payload`  but worked right away when doing that!